# PHP 7 Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Tags: php, ubuntu

php скрипт, запускаю на системе ubuntu, стоит php7, при попытке запуска скрипта командой php script.php выдает ошибку

> PHP 7 Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()  on line 11

строка 11 вот:

```
$connect_to_db = mysqli_connect($domain, $username, $password, $db)
```

в чем может быть проблема? Если запускать этот же скрипт через веб, он работает

Comment: В php.ini раскомментируйте строку `extension=mysqli.so` (примерный вид) и перезапустите php.

Comment: Используйте PDO уже...

Comment: @Visman в php.ini который в /etc/php/7.0/cli ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

надо поставить mysql extension для php7.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysqlnd
sudo phpenmod mysqlnd 
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: стоит последней версии

Comment: @Drop выведите результат phpinfo(); нужна строчка PHP Version в верху и есть ли mysqli совпадения.

Comment: @ tcpack4, PHP Version 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.17.04.1
http://prntscr.com/g318oo

Comment: @Drop попробуйте обновленную команду выше.

Comment: @ tcpack4,вот так пишет
Note, selecting 'php7.0-mysql' instead of 'php7.0-mysqlnd'
php7.0-mysql is already the newest version (7.0.18-0ubuntu0.17.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.

Comment: @Drop sudo phpenmod mysqlnd && sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 1):

Вероятнее всего у Вас не установлен mysqli PHP extension .
Установить можно этой командой:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

Comment: стоит последней версии